# Is it possible to manipulate pdf files in Visual Basic without an external library/SDK?

Tags: file, pdf, merge, basic

I am looking at how to implement PDF merging with raw VB code so that the code may be invoked by a bot for business process automation.

The software used to create the bot provides a function to invoke VB code, but I don't believe it can access any externally imported libraries because it expects plain source, so I essentially need to produce code that one could run in a VB shell environment without anything fancy (or convenient, it seems).

All the research I've done so far point me in the direction of external packages I would need to install, such as iText; this is what I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: To "manipulate" files?  Sure.  Depends entirely on your definition of manipulation, however.

Comment: yes, I want to append/merge multiple PDF documents into one. I know there are some software apps and countless source libraries for that, but I need to figure it out with VB and no external references

Answer (score 1):

(previous iText employee here)

PDF is not an easy (binary) format.
Essentially, blobs of information (text that has to be rendered, fonts, images, vector graphics, etc) are compressed and gathered into objects.

Each object gets a number. Objects are allowed to reference eachother (a piece of text might say 'I want to be rendered with font 4433')

All object numbers and their byte offset in the file are gathered in the crossreference (often called XREF) table.

A PDF includes a 'Pages' dictionary object that tells the viewer which objects belong on which page.

In order to merge PDF files, you would need to:
 - read all XREF tables of all files
 - adjust all of those to the correct byte offset
 - update various dictionary objects within the PDF file that tell it where all the objects per page are kept

This is by no means a trivial task, but it can be done using only VB.

If you are serious about implementing a robust, scalable version of this of tool, perhaps it's better to look at the iText sourcecode and try to port it to VB?